# jquery selector based on name and then class name

Tags: jquery

I have a  HTML see below

[image]

here i trying to get all  Li whose has class selectedLi,

I am  trying

```
$("#coverage_ul li .selectedLi");
```

but this was not returning any thing

Comment: use *$("coverage_ul li.selectedLi")* ....that should resolve your issue

Comment: ...or just `$("#coverage_ul .selectedLi");` will work as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the space between `li` and `.selectedLi`:

```
$('#coverage li.selectedLi')
```

As it stands it's looking for a *descendent* of the `li` with that class, not an `li` *with* that class.

(FWIW, using `selectedLi` as the class name is probably a little over-the-top - it would be quite normal to just use `selected` and rely on the fact that the element is a `<li>` per the selector to choose the appropriate styles).

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$("#coverage_ul li.selectedLi") 
//^^^^^^^^^^^remove space here between li and .selectedLi
```

if you use any selector with class then

first write element type then its (class or id) in your case like below

```
elementtype       class or id       =last result
li                .selectedLi       =li.selectedLi
```

Comment: The bottom section of your answer is very confusing, IMHO.

Comment: perhaps, but the wording and layout make that far from obvious.

Comment: sorry @Alnitak can you suggest me how it write i want to explain that how OP make its selector

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#coverage_ul li.selectedLi")
```

### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mLK6g/2/)